# What is the type of jest.doMock('winston')

Tags: jquery, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am using jest and typescript and I want to test some code that is using winston logger as dependancy. I am struggling with the type I should expect from `jest.doMock`

Here is an extract of my setup.

```js
describe('Logger unit tests', () => {
  let getLogger: GetLogger
  let winston: jest.Mocked<any>

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.doMock('winston', () => ({
      config: {
        syslog: {
          levels: {
            info: 3,
          },
        },
      },
      createLogger: jest.fn(),
      format: {
        colorize: jest.fn(),
        combine: jest.fn(),
        json: jest.fn(),
        label: jest.fn(),
        printf: jest.fn(),
        splat: jest.fn(),
        timestamp: jest.fn(),
      },
      transports: {
        Console: jest.fn(),
      },
    }))
    winston = require('winston')
   })
  })
```

It is fine, tests are passing, typescript is not complaining but I would love to remove the `any` in `let winston: jest.Mocked<any>` but I don't know what I should put.

I tried stuffs like

```js
import * as Winston from 'winston'


describe('Logger unit tests', () => {
  let getLogger: GetLogger
  let winston: jest.Mocked<typeof Winston>
...
```

But I have types error like this one.

[image: Types error]

Typescript does not consider that nested methods are jest function

How can I achieve that ?